# extrude plane along axes of cube

Tags: extrude

I want to extrude a face along the rotation of a the roof. How do i do that? Is there a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom orientation: Select the face, open the *Transform Orientations* panel and click on the "+" button:

[image]

The orientation is now selected by default, extrude along X, Y or Z, it will follow the face orientation:

[image]

Comment: thanks learn something new today :).

Comment: it's not good topology though, you should give some thickness to your roof